# CGAffineTransform concatenating two matrices vs applying one to the other

Tags: swift, cgaffinetransform

In this example below, why the first matrix is equal to the third, not the second?

```
let t1 = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)
    .concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 50, y: 50))

let t2 = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2).translatedBy(x: 50, y: 50)

let t3 = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 50, y: 50).scaledBy(x: 2, y: 2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid confusion with names, I'm renaming your variables from `tN` to `rN`:

```
let r1 = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)
    .concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 50, y: 50))

let r2 = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2).translatedBy(x: 50, y: 50)

let r3 = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 50, y: 50).scaledBy(x: 2, y: 2)
```

It really does seem backwards. And the documentation for the methods doesn't really make it clear for any of the math other than for the `concatenating` function.

As you can see in the documentation for `concatenating`:

> A new affine transformation matrix. That is, t’ = t1*t2.

In your sample code for the `r1` variable this is `scale * translate`.

That part seems clear enough.

As for the `translatedBy` and `scaledBy` functions you need to look at the Objective-C header file for the corresponding functions of `CGAffineTransformTranslate` and `CGAffineTransformScale`.

For `CGAffineTransformTranslate` you see the comment:

> Translate t by (tx, ty) and return the result:
>        t' = [ 1 0 0 1 tx ty ] * t

And for `CGAffineTransformScale` you see:

> Scale t by (sx, sy) and return the result:
>        t' = [ sx 0 0 sy 0 0 ] * t

This information tells us that `let r = t.translatedBy(t2)` is equivalent to `t' = t2 * t`. Of course the `scaledBy` and `rotatedBy` are similar.

This means that this line in your code:

```
let r3 = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 50, y: 50).scaledBy(x: 2, y: 2)
```

is the same as:

```
let r3 = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2).concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 50, y: 50))
```

and not:

```
let r3 = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 50, y: 50).concatenating(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2))
```

This is why in your sample code, `r1` is equal to `r3`. Reading those 2nd two lines like English leads to the idea that the matrices are concatenated in the reverse order.

Comment: I suspected as much but didn't have the time to look into it fully. Nice answer :D

Comment: @rmaddy good point that they mention reverse order in the docs. Who knows what they were thinking when making it like this, but at least we know that's by design. Thanks.